# Check if non optional array of string is empty at specific index Swift. Without using count function

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of strings and I want to check if the array at index is empty than I have to insert element, if it is not empty, I have to change the value of this element.
I tried this:

```
    var AnsArray = [String]()
    let a_id = "Hello"
    if (AnsArray[Indexpath.row].isEmpty){
    AnsArray.insert(a_id, at: Indexpath.row)
    }
    else {
        AnsArray[Indexpath.row] = a_id
    }
```

But it is giving an error:

> fatal error: Index out of range

I also tried this:

```
if (AnsArray[Indexpath.row] == "" ) {
        AnsArray.insert(a_id, at: Indexpath.row)
    }
    else {
        AnsArray[Indexpath.row] = a_id
    }
```

It is also giving the same error.

> Note: I can not use array.count because array can hold elements in
>   specific index for example at index = 0 it can be empty and at index =
>   2 it can be stored some data.

Comment: Is this a typo in your question? You have `QuestArray` on the 1st line but then the rest of the code uses `AnsArray`.

Comment: Considering your note I would like to mention that you can not have empty blocks in an array. You have to put something at index 0 & 1 if you intend to put a particular value/object at index 2. It might be a simple object but it must have previous indices filled

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited thanx for correcting

Comment: Your main error is related to cell count on list view (tableview or collection view) your are using , Please post whole code of controller .

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the array is empty and indexPath.row is 17?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to access item outside the bounds of an array. Your array is empty, so calling `AnsArray[whateverIndexPath]` will always result in this error.

What's important is that `Array` cannot hold `nil` values - if your array is empty, you can't just "check at speciffic index", like you described you want to.

Also, you can't `insert` an item in empty array - the index you insert at must be already valid before the insertion.

So, if you want to insert something to an array, you need to start at the very beginning, with `append`. Or, alternatively, pre-populate your array with empty strings.

```
AnsArray = [String](repeating: "", count: yourDesiredArrayCount)

if (AnsArray[Indexpath.row].isEmpty){
    AnsArray[Indexpath.row] = "newValue"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check first index is available.if you directly access element by index you may get Index out of range  exception if it don't have. So you can check by Indices with contains property

```
if AnsArray.indices.contains(YOUR_INDEX) {
     //Now you can check whether element is empty or not.
     // Do your tuffs
}else {
   //insert new element
}
```